# How was a standard windows 7 user able to delete files under C:\Program Files?

Tags: c++, windows, security, permissions, delete-file

In c++, the DeleteFile() function shouldn't allow standard users  to delete files under C:\Program Files, but someone running the program was able to do this!

How is this possible??

Under Properties | Security for C:\Program Files, none of entries have write or modify access.

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Answer (score 0):

Found the cause: An intervening folder between C:\Program Files and the folder standard users could change had DIFFERENT permissions, which were inherited.  Mystery solved.